# How to create multidimensional array with use deep level variable

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have two single arrays. data and deep_level.

```
// data
array {
  [0] => "orders",
  [1] => "order",
  [2] => "id",
  [3] => "code",
  [4] => "products",
  [5] => "product",
  [6] => "id",
  [7] => "title",
  [8] => "variants",
  [9] => "variant",
  [10] => "id",
  [11] => "param",
  [12] => "options",
  [13] => "option",
  [14] => "id",
  [15] => "param"
}
```

and

```
// deep_level
array {
  [0] => 0,
  [1] => 1,
  [2] => 2,
  [3] => 2,
  [4] => 2,
  [5] => 3,
  [6] => 4,
  [7] => 4,
  [8] => 4,
  [9] => 5,
  [10] => 6,
  [11] => 6,
  [12] => 4,
  [13] => 5,
  [14] => 6,
  [15] => 6
}
```

key($data)==key($deep_level)

**How to create a multidimensional array** from these data like this?

```
array(1) {
  ["orders"] => array {
    ["order"] => array {
      ["id"] => null,
      ["title"] => null,
      ["products"] => array {
        ["product"] => array {
          ["id"] => null,
          ["title"] => null,
          ["variants"] => array {
            ["variant"] => array {
              ["id"] => null,
              ["param"] => null
            }
          },
          ["options"] => array {
            ["option"] => array {
              ["id"] => null,
              ["param"] => null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Deep level is not fixed and it can be more deeper or less. I think, this is maybe thing for recursive `function()` but im newbie in that.

Comment: Have you tried anything - and more important, why are you storing your data into two seperate arrays?

Comment: And you know how and want help me or do you want only lecture what dont you like. Yes ofcourse i tried something. Otherwise I would not ask for help here

Comment: Hi @netoper, asking for what you have tried is done to be able to help you better. It's easier to see what the problem is if you show what you have tried and what didn't work as expected. Please don't dismiss comments asking for more detail and context.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm nervous little bit because i spend more time with this thing without success. You are right.

Comment: The thing is - If possible I would solve the source of this two arrays, because it's error prone (i.e. what if the second array is `[0,1,4]`) and I currently see no benefit of storing a tree structure in two arrays.

Comment: Thank you but whole thing is more complexed and this is only one piece from that. I stand on it. Case `[0,1,4]` never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, this could be done without recursion, if you iterate over the array and store references to the previous levels inside an array. Doing this, the whole thing becomes pretty straight forward.

```
function buildTree($data, $deep) {
    $tree = [];
    $levels = [0 => &$tree];
    foreach ($data as $i => $item) {
        $level = $deep[$i];
        $pos = max(0, $level - 1);
        $levels[$pos][$item] = [];
        $levels[$level] = &$levels[$pos][$item];
        $current = $level;
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Notice, that this method has no error checks, so your deep level array should be valid and starts with `0` or the output will be anything, but not what you expect.

Comment: Thank You! Only for clarify. Here is sample of whole thing (http://www.showcase.sk/php/) and I am looking for solution how to do. Your code is very helpful.